# is there a way to auto recompile with crystal (aka nodemon / supervisor )

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm just learning the language and playing with a file I'd like to recompile each time there are changes.

Is there an equivalent to `watch` or like `nodemon` in the node world?

Alternatively a little shellscript to kill the running app when changes are noticed?

Answer (score 4):

In https://github.com/benoist/carbon-crystal/blob/master/Guardfile they use https://github.com/guard/guard . Any tool you can chain with filesystem events to run `crystal spec` should do the trick. I haven't tried it though.

As a native crystal interpreter of Guardfiles you can use https://github.com/f/guardian

Since the manifest shard.yml does not include the main files to compile for the project itself there is no way to have that inside crystal cli directly.